# Assinatura HTML trocando endereço de Imagem por Link

Tags: html, android, email

Estou criando uma assinatura HTML para os e-mails, porém percebi um problema que ocorre somente no Android, e impede que as imagens sejam carregadas corretamente.

Ele substitui o endereço da imagem por um link, conforme abaixo (depois de examinar o codigo fonte do e-mail recebido):

```html
<img src="meusite.com.br/img.png" alt="Imagem" width="800" height="109" border="0">

<img src="<a href='meusite.com.br/img.png' target='_blank'>meusite.com.br/img.png
</a>" alt="Imagem" width="800" height="109" border="0">
```

Ou seja ele converte o endereço:

```
meusite.com.br/img.png
```

em

```html
<a href='meusite.com.br/img.png' target='_blank'>meusite.com.br/img.png
</a>
```

Existe alguma forma de escapar isto?

Comment: A tag <img> é sem fechar o /> assim mesmo?

Comment: Por que você tem uma tag `<a>` dentro do `src` da imagem?

Comment: Não fui eu quem adicionou essa <a> no src, é quando eu insiro esse codigo como assinatura no email em qualquer aplicativo android